# bind params in batch insert in yii 1.0

Tags: yii, batch-insert

I want to Copy one record and update sevaral fields and paste it multiple times in same table. I want to do this operation in one SQL query so i'm thinking for batchinsert but i'm not able to use bind params method.

```
INSERT INTO table (<field>, <field>, <total 100 fields>) VALUES . implode(",", $values);
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> There are no any command of batchinsert in YII1

Checkout this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/45623-multi-insert-rows/

Might be you can solve your issue with this.

Comment: I do really appriciate your answer. I want to bind params which doesn't mentioned there.

Below is my custom query which will converted in multiinsert 

~INSERT INTO `table` (`<field>`, `<field>`, <total 100 fields>) VALUES . implode(",", $values);~